# json data validation with input values using angular Js and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I have got json  data in a file (/static/models.json) like this in angular JS project ..

```
{
    "familyType": {
        "A650": [{
            "partID": "2630_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2690_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2680_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2600_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2620_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2610_H"
        }],
        "S400": [{
                "partID": "S500_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S600_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S700_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S800_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S900_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S100_Aru"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have got below function with parameters passing into that method (**Part_id1, Part_id2**)  and inside the function..I have got two family  types (A650,S400) and  i need to check whether the two input  part_Id's(**Part_id1, Part_id2**) are belongs to same family or not (i.e either **A650** or **S400** )

If the two  part_id's(**Part_id1, Part_id2**) are from different family types i need to alert user ... 
how can we traverse through json file and compare the part_ID's in both the family types ..

```
$scope.ValidateModelList = function(Part_id1, Part_id2, $http) {
     if ($scope.firTable.selectedRowsCount != 0) {
         $http.get("/static/models.json")
             .success(function(response) {
                 $scope.names = response;
             });
         // here i am storing json data in $scope.names object
         //  here i need to check that the part_ids with the family
     }
 }
```

Would any one please help on this that would be very grateful to me....

Many thanks in advance ....

**Update**

```
function ValidateModel(partIDlist){

             alert('2');
             var data = stubdata; // Stubdata is actual json data mentioned above
             var partIdResult = [];
             for (var key in data.familyType) {

                 angular.forEach(data.familyType[key], function (object) {

                     angular.forEach(partIDlist, function (partId) {

                         if (partId == object.partID) {
                             partIdResult.push({
                                 value: partId, family: key
                             });
                         }
                     });
                 });
             }

             for (var i = 0; i < partIdResult.length; i++) {
                // alert(partIdResult.length);
                //alert(partIdResult.family);
                alert(JSON.stringify(partIdResult))
                alert(partIdResult.family); // this is giving undefined value
             alert(partIdResult[0].family);

                 if (partIdResult.family === partIdResult[0].family){
                     alert('yes');
                     alert("part_id's are same");
                 }
                 else if (partIdResult.family !== partIdResult[0].family) {
                     alert("part_id's not same");
                 }
             }
         }
```

here I am passing  a list like this ..

**var partIDlist= ["S900_Aru", "S500_Aru", "2610_H"];**

and I am getting   **alert(JSON.stringify(partIdResult))** **partIdResult** as like this

```
 [{"value":"S900_Aru","family":"S400"},
 {"value":"S500_Aru","family":"S400"},
 {"value":"2610_H","family":"A650"}]
```

I should get these three part_id's are not belong to same model .. instead of this I am getting part_id's are belongs to same

could you please help on this ... Many thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First succes is deprecated use .then instead. 2nd data are stored under response.data.

```
.then(function(response) {
     var data = response.data;
     var partId2Family = null, partId1Family = null;

     for(var key in data.familyType){
         angular.forEach(data.familyType[key], function(object){
              if(Part_id1 == object.partID){
                  partId1Family = key;
              }
              if(Part_id2 == object.partID){
                  partId2Family = key;
              }
         })
     }     
     if(partId1Family !== PartId2Family){
          // warning
     }         
}
```

This should do the trick.

Edit : array version

```
.then(function(response) {
     var data = response.data;
    var partIdResult = [];
     for(var key in data.familyType){
         angular.forEach(data.familyType[key], function(object){
              angular.forEach(partIds, function(partId){
                   if(partId == object.partID){
                        partIdResult.push({value:partId, family:key});
                   }
              });
         })
     }     
     for(var i = 1; i < partIdResult.length; i++){
         if(partIdResult[i].family !== partIdResult[0].family){
                //error
         }
     }      
}
```

Comment: hi many thanks .. one more query.. if we got array list with list of part_id's..... this time how can we check whether all are belongs to same family or not ...

Comment: i edited and added the array version. Note : check underscorejs on the net, it's a really usefull library that provide utility function to write cleaner code when working with loops an array or object properties.

Comment: No problem they're just making you doing things already uglier with more risk of creating bugs and time consuming for nothing, that's their problem i guess. Let's say you can check it for your own personnal interest if you want.

Comment: is it applicable to this scenario also (even if i increased more familytypes in json file ...)(S400,A650 .. and so on..)

Comment: since familytype is not array i am getting error at this line 'var key in data.familyType'  familtyType is undefined..

Comment: the for in statement in javascript is not made to loop into an array but to loop into the leys of an object. Check the format of your data, what i wrote should be fine according to what you show in your post. Check last part of this post http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: sorry to disturb you  .. I am getting undefined value for this "partIdResult.family" when i am passing list as input to that method .. could you please help on this.....

Comment: I wrote that method to be used by $http. Just move away the 1st line of my function and name the parameter to be passed data and you should be fine. If not use your browser debogguer and put a breakpoint to inspect your datas to see what does not match with this code.

Comment: ok do you have any alerts ? like the 'yes' or none ? By the way the `if (partIdResult.family !== partIdResult[0].family)` is not relevant here the else is enough.

Comment: I need to show two alerts if they are the same or not both ... and  "partIdResult.family" is giving undefined value when i put that in alert .. i updated my question with partIdresult ..

Comment: my bad forgot the `[i]` in the loop. partIdResult is an array so of course `.family` give `undefined` just replace all `partIdResult.family`by `partIdResult[i].family` in your loop

Answer (score 1):

```
var partsList = {
    "familyType": {
        "A650": [{
            "partID": "2630_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2690_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2680_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2600_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2620_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2610_H"
        }],
        "S400": [{
                "partID": "S500_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S600_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S700_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S800_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S900_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S100_Aru"
            }
        ]
    }
};

function ValidateModelList(Part_id1, Part_id2){

    var part_id_1_family = getPartFamily(Part_id1);
  var part_id_2_family = getPartFamily(Part_id2)
  //alert(part_id_1_family + ", " + part_id_2_family);
    //console.log("part_id_1_family", part_id_1_family);
  //console.log("part_id_2_family", part_id_2_family);
    if(part_id_1_family != part_id_2_family) alert("parts are from different families!");
    else alert("parts from same family.")
}

function getPartFamily(part_id)
{
    var familyType = partsList.familyType;
  // loop through family type
    for(var family in familyType)
  {
    if(!familyType.hasOwnProperty(family)) continue;
    //loop through part objects in this family
    for(var j = 0; j < familyType[family].length; j++)
    {
        // check if parts id is in this array
        if(part_id == familyType[family][j].partID) return family;
    }
  }
    return false;
}

ValidateModelList("2630_H", "S900_Aru");

ValidateModelList("S600_Aru", "S900_Aru");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ladmwdvt/4/

Comment: hi many thanks ..  if we got array list with list of part_id's..... this time how can we check whether all are belongs to same family or not..

Answer (score 0):

Though not clear about your question, below is something how you would check.

```
Object.keys(type.familyType).forEach(function(key,index) {
   if(key === Part_id1 || key === Part_id2){
    //do something
     } else {
    //do something else
   }
});
```

A Fiddle to play with.

https://jsfiddle.net/2cgww6ec/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var t = {
    "familyType": {
        "A650": [{
            "partID": "2630_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2690_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2680_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2600_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2620_H"
        }, {
            "partID": "2610_H"
        }],
        "S400": [{
                "partID": "S500_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S600_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S700_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S800_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S900_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S100_Aru"
            }
        ]
    }
};

search("2630_H","2620_H");

function search(ida,idb) {
  $.each(t['familyType'], function(a, b) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(b);
    if(str.indexOf(ida)>=0 && str.indexOf(idb) >=0){
      alert("same family :  " + a);
      return;
    } 
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p> search("2630_H","2620_H") will called <p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = {
    "familyType": {
        "A650": [
            {
                "partID": "2630_H"
            }, {
                "partID": "2690_H"
            }, {
                "partID": "2680_H"
            }, {
                "partID": "2600_H"
            }, {
                "partID": "2620_H"
            }, {
                "partID": "2610_H"
            }
        ],
        "S400": [
            {
                "partID": "S500_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S600_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S700_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S800_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S900_Aru"
            }, {
                "partID": "S100_Aru"
            }
        ]
    }
};

for (familyid in obj.familyType){
    obj.familyTyle[familyid].forEach(function(key){
        if(key.partID == Part_id1) family1 = familyid;
        if(key.partID == Part_id2) family2 = familyid;
    });
}

if(family1 === family2){
    alert('parts are same');
}
```

Comment: Hi in future more family types will add so in that case i cannot hard code each family like this "obj.familyType.A650."  .......  is there any generic way ...